# Using a hash to collect statistics on word usage

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an empty hash and want to populate it with word frequencies.
If the hash encounters a new word, it must initiate that word as a key. If it finds a word it has seen before, it simply increments that key's value. Is there a refactored version of this code?

```
my_hash = {}
@huge_word_list.words.each do |word|
    my_hash[word] ? my_hash[word] += 1 : my_hash[word] = 1
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my preferred way to do it, explicit and concise:

```
@huge_word_list.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |word, h| h[word] += 1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize the hash with a default value, in this case 0:

```
my_hash = Hash.new(0)
@huge_word_list.words.each { |word| my_hash[word] += 1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would populate the hash `Hash.new(0)`, but since there are already 237 answers that do that, I'll try another away:

```
def count_words(words)
  h = words.group_by { |w| w }
  h.merge(h) { |*_,a| a.size }
end

text =<<_
Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers for the piper whose
name is also Peter. After doing so, Peter pickled a peck of peppers
he picked.
_

words = text.tr(".,;:?'\"()",'').downcase.split
  #=> ["peter", "piper", "picked", "a", "peck", "of", "pickled",
  #    "peppers", "for", "the", "piper", "whose", "name", "is",
  #    "also", "peter", "after", "doing", "so", "peter", "pickled",
  #    "a", "peck", "of", "peppers", "he", "picked"] 

count_words(words)
  #=> {"peter"=>3, "piper"=>2, "picked"=>2, "a"=>2, "peck"=>2,
  #    "of"=>2, "pickled"=>2, "peppers"=>2, "for"=>1, "the"=>1,
  #    "whose"=>1, "name"=>1, "is"=>1, "also"=>1, "after"=>1,
  #    "doing"=>1, "so"=>1, "he"=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@huge_word_list.words.inject({}) { |h, word| h[word] = h[word].to_i + 1; h }
```